# Efficiently creating a nested for loop x layers deep

Tags: objective-c

This may be a simple thing to do, but I need to create a loop structure in such a way that it loops y^x times to create all possible combinations of x and y. For example, if there were 4 x's and each x had 2 y's, I would want to do something like:

```
for(int a=0; a < y; a++){
    for(int b=0; b < y; b++){
        for(int c=0; c < y; c++){
            for(int d=0; d < y; d++){
                // create a new object with values of a, b, c, d
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, create x number of nested for loops to create a total of y^x objects (in this case, 16 of them). What would be the simplest and most efficient way to do this, assuming the values x and y can change? I'm assuming recursion may be involved in some way, but I'm not 100% sure how to go about it.

Comment: Seems like a bad design choice, what's your final purpose?

Comment: I'm trying to create every possible combination of musical scales. There are 12 tones in the chromatic scale system. My idea was to do something like this to generate every possible combination of 1 to 12 tone scales possible (a total of 4,096 combinations). I wanted to keep the number of tones variable to keep the potential open for non-chromatic scale systems (such as some Eastern scales with 40+ tones per scale).

Comment: recursion is definitely the way to go, check the answers below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do not know the level of nesting at compile time, you need to use recursion: the function should have a single loop representing `k`-th nesting level, and continue calling itself recursively until the `N`-th level is reached:

```
-(void) nestAtLevel:(int)k withItems:(int[])items from:(int) from to:(int)to {
    if (k >= 0) {
        for (items[k] = from ; items[k] != to ; items[k]++) {
            [self nestAtLevel:k-1 withItems:items from:from to:to];
        }
    } else {
        // Use the indexes produced recursively: the current values are in items 1..N-1
        [self creatObjectsWithIndexes:items];
    }
}
```

The initial call should look like this:

```
int items[5];
[self nestAtLevel:4 withItems:items from:0 to:4];
```

I assume that there is also a function `creatObjectsWithIndexes` that takes an array of index items, and produces an object from them.

Comment: Actually, one more brief question about this -- if I'm using something like this as a designated initializer for a class when the program is first run, would I want to perform this recursion on a separate thread? I was thinking that if k is 12 and n is 2, then that's 4,096 objects that createObjectsWithIndexes is creating -- wouldn't that be a lot for the main thread to deal with? Again, novice here, so sorry if this is a foolish question.

Comment: @NateKimball This depends a lot on what you do these 4096 times: if it is something fast, 4096 is not a lot; if it's something slow, offloading to a separate thread may be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Standard way to do it would be to use recursion.

You will have function like that:

```
void foo(int level, const int max_depth) {
    if (level == max_depth) {
         // code from final loop
         return;
    } else {
        for (...) {
            foo(level+1, max_depth);
        }
    }
 }
```

Now you can have arbitrary number of levels of nesting passed in **max_depth**.